# Adding validation to jQuery form radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, radio-button

I'm working on a form where I need to determine if a radio button is selected using jQuery form validation. There's probably a super easy solution but I haven't figured it out. Here's my snippets of code:

```
$bodyFormContainer.append('<div class="formMediumCopy">Are you a Sport&Health member?</div> <br /> <input type="radio" class="" name="webform_member" id="control_COLUMN170_0" value="Member" /> &nbsp; <div class="formMediumCopy">Member</div> <input type="radio" class="" name="webform_member" id="control_COLUMN170_1" value="Non-Member" /> &nbsp; <div class="formMediumCopy">Non-Member</div> <br />')
                .append('<a class="blueButton freePassBtn" href="javascript:FreeTNTHelper.postForm(this);" onclick="return FreeTNTHelper.validateData();" id="freePassBtn">Send Your Request<img src="/images/arrow_btn.png" width="11" height="17" alt="" /></a>');
```

For the validation, I have:

```
var FreeTNTHelper = {
validateData: function () {
if (document.getElementById('control_COLUMN170:checked').length < 0) {
        alert("Please indicate if you're a member or non-member.");
        document.getElementById('control_COLUMN170').focus();
        return (false);
    }
},
```

The validation above isn't working. If the radio button is not selected, I need a popup that asks the person if they are a member or non-member.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a radio box has one selected by default. I would set a default selection there probably to non member. Also, you won't really need the id attribute.

After that, you can test for

```
if($("input[name='webform_member']").val() == "Member"){
    //process code here
} else {
    //process code here    
}
```

here is a fiddle snippit
[Fiddle for values](http://jsfiddle.net/pyBhA/)

Answer (score -1):

You can get the value of an input like this:

```
$("input#id").val();//1 if checked, 0 if not checked
```

Comment: Does this work when there are two options? To clarify my original post, I need a notification to pop up if neither option is selected. 

I tried plugging in your suggestion like this:

'if (document.getElementById('control_COLUMN170_0').val(0) && document.getElementById('control_COLUMN170_1').val(0)) {
            alert("Please indicate if you're a member or non-member.");
            document.getElementById('control_COLUMN170').focus();
            return (false);'

Will that check if either option is not selected?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh ok. Her you go: if (!$("input[name='nameOfRadioButtons']:checked").val()) {
   alert('None are checked!');
}

Comment: This would not return 1 or 0. It would actually return the string "Member" or "Non-Member"

Comment: Oops you're right! For some reason I thought .val() was :checked.